# bash: cd: <path> : No such file or directory

Tags: filesystems, directory, cd-command

[image]

I upgraded to the latest version of Kali Linux and all of a sudden I can't open up files. The file manager shows the files exist and I can get in them through the file manager but cannot do so through the CL.

Comment: @Chima, [_Please_ don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/170373).

Comment: Fair response @ikkachu. I've deleted my comments as they no longer have context as they were in response to a user that has since deleted their comments. A basic tutorial would have likely resolved the user's problem. I was basically protesting the closing of this question under the Kali Linux duplicate go-to.

Comment: @ilkkachu noted.

Comment: @Mark whatever you say

Comment: @Crypteya, yep, _that_ part I can understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all `/` is a directory, so if you use: `cd /something` it means that change to directory `something` which is inside `/` directory.

You are in `/opt` directory and you are having three directories there:

```
Teeth Veil Pycharm-community-2018.3.4
```

Now if you want to enter in any of these directories, you should use command:

```
cd directory_name
```

Or

```
cd /opt/directory_name
```

Not **cd /directory_name** because it will change to directory_name in `/`.

And same for the `Downloads` and `Desktop` directories. If you are in the `home`directory then try to use:

```
cd Desktop
```

or

```
cd /root/Desktop
```

Not **cd /Desktop**.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for:

```
cd Desktop
```

or

```
cd /root/Desktop
```

Not `cd /Desktop` as you have it.

**Explanation**

The issue that you're having is that you are trying to go to an absolute path rather than a relative path. You should research these terms and understand the significance of placing a `/` at the beginning of your path. Basically, absolute paths start from the root directory (what you were trying to use), and relative paths start from the working directory of your shell.

For more info, try reading here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/absolute-relative-pathnames-unix/